# Responding to a HTTP Get with an SSE

Tags: html, node.js, server-sent-events

I am experimenting with HTML5 and node.js.  I have tested out Server Sent Events and they worked fine(Refering to [this example](https://github.com/cheeyeo/Server-Sent-Events-with-Node-JS)).

Next I tried replying to a button press with an SSE. On pressing the "Increment" button I pick a number from a text box and pass it to the server using a GET message. The server will then respond with an event containing the incremented number. The eventListener will then update the text box with the received number. I have also added a "Message area" on the HTML page to log messages.

That was the plan. But when I click the button the browser shows a "downloading" operation is in progress in the bottom of the window but it never completes and the result is not updated on the screen nor is the message displayed in the bottom of the page.

The events work fine when i send them at the load of the page. But when I send it in response to a GET message the HTML page doesn't show any response.

Here is the HTML section.

```
<form action="/upload" method="get">
<p>Set the temperature and click on send</p>
<input name="temperature" id="TemperatureBox" type="text" value = "33" />
<button type="submit" onclick="form.action='http://localhost:8888/Increment'">Increment</button>
```

I have added handlers for messages and for a "temperature event" which will update the Temperature box

```
var source = new EventSource('/events');

source.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  //code to display message
}, false);

source.addEventListener('TemperatureValueUpdate', function(e) {
        AddLog('TemperatureValueUpdate Listener >> lastEventID: ' + (e.lastEventId || '--') +
               ', e.data: ' + e.data
        + 'Current value of text box: ' +  document.getElementById('TemperatureBox').value);
        document.getElementById('TemperatureBox').value= e.data;

}, false);
```

In the node.js script i am sending a message and a TemperatureValueUpdate

```
function constructTemperature(response, id, data) {
console.log("Sending Temperature event");
//  response.write('id: ' + (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString()+ '\n');
 // response.write("data: " + 'Teperature event sent '+ '\n\n');

response.write('event: ' + 'TemperatureValueUpdate' + '\n');
response.write('id: ' + id + '\n');
response.write("data: " + data + '\n\n');

console.log("Finished Temperature event"); }
```

I have also responded to the "/events" URL on the page load with a 200 reply:

```
response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream','Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Connection': 'keep-alive' });
```

I have even tried the following

- Sending a 202/204 response before sending the events
- sending a response.end() before/after sending the events
- Sending a 'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream' before each event

But they don't produce the desired result. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you are calling the constructTemperature() function when you do the form submit. If that is the case you are on a different connection from the EventSource. So you need to store the data to return to the client somewhere on the server and call constructTemperature() in the request originating from the EventSource.

Comment: Let me see if I understood. When i start the page the url is `http://localhost:8888//MyApp` and when i press the button the url sent is `http://localhost:8888/Increment?temperature=33`. By different connection , do you mean to say that my pathname should remain the same throughout  the application? So for incrementing the number I should use something like `http://localhost:8888//MyApp?operation=Increment&temperature=33` instead of the current one.

Comment: Not quite. The URL the EventSource is looking for event is `http://localhost:8888/events`. The response from that URL should contain the response from the `constructTemperature()` function.

Comment: I tried changing the url for all HTTP requests to `http://localhost:8888/MyApp` and registering the event source as `var source = new EventSource('/MyApp');`. i differentiate based on the `req.headers.accept =='text/event-stream' condition;  The only difference is that the browser does not show the downloading box forever but the problem still persists.